# Using ARM Linux kernel helper functions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm

I am trying hard to understand how [ARM kernel helper functions](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm/kernel_user_helpers.txt) are supposed to work in Linux.

I am debugging a program that tries use them but they seem to cause severe stack corruption and SIGILL CPU exceptions.

One of my problem is figuring out whether they are built into the kernel I have. Looking at the kernel source, however, I was not able to devise a compilation flag to enable/disable them.

Another problem that I have is that my gdb is not able to examine the corresponding area : neither can I read memory at

```
 0xffff0ffc ; __kuser_helper_version
```

nor can I disassemble the functions.

I tried writing a simple program to read the API level :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, char **argv ){
    int * ptr = (int *)0xffff0ffc;
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
}
```

and, somewhat unsurprisingly, I'm getting a segmentation fault.

Hence my question : how can a userland program leverage these functions, and how can application debugger follow up in these ?

Comment: Sounds like your kernel is built without them - check CONFIG_KUSER_HELPERS. Also note that they're really only for pre-ARMv6 systems anyway, so if you're on a more modern machine you don't need to care.

Comment: OK, looks like they should not be called in the first place then. The kernel flag you mention definitely isn't part of my config, which is ARMv7-A

Comment: You can check `proc/self/maps` to see if the kernel has mapped the region.  All functions are available in ARMv6+ user mode and don't require kernel help.  The option to exclude it is to prevent *return oriented programming* exploits; the helper page has very low resource overhead.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion : it is indeed confirming that my kernel lacks those functions. I am not too sure why the code I debug does not cause a memory violation like my test code does, though, and why this was not built into the kernel in the first place, for the sake of backware compatibility.